# Limit time usage on certain websites

Tags: windows, time-management, internet, parental-control

I need software (for Windows; preferably for Android too) that monitors and restricts internet usage. It would have to split websites in 3 categories:

- **Allowed**. Unrestricted access, as often as wanted and whenever wanted.
- **Restricted**. Access is permitted but only for a limited amount of time (e.g. 30 minutes each day) and I can grant them extra time remotely.
- **Disallowed**. Access to these websites is permanently unavailable.

Moreover, there should be no easy way to disable the program as a non-admin to go around the blocking.

As easy as it sounds, I fail to find a suitable program. [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/) is an example of an app that allows to categorize websites and track time accordingly. Several parental control apps allow restricting the total web time, but without the ability to make certain websites not count towards that total time limit. I'm essentially looking for something that mixes both. Any recommendations?

Comment: Related: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10840/6834

Comment: Do you mean `Network Firewall` ?!

Comment: @AminSaghi can you clarify what you mean? I see many software that makes a network firewall but none of them has a time credit system like I requested.

Comment: @user1111929 I understand. It sounds like parental control software. The closest thing I could find that has quota time is [WebSense](http://www.websense.com/support/article/kbarticle/What-is-quota-time-and-how-does-it-work). [K9 Web Protection](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/) may also have it but it's not clear in the [features page](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/aboutk9/product-features). I have not tested them so I'm not posting a full answer

Comment: Websense has quota time, but unfortunately no system to award extra time. Going physically to the computer and modify the remaining time every time I need to grant the user extra time, is not feasible, unfortunately.

Comment: You can either try 'FocalFilter' or 'Cold Turkey'.

Comment: Do you have access to the router? I use my Fritz Box for that, which may (or may not) be available for your router as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try LeechBlock, is a Firefox addon that allows you to do:

- Disallow some times forever or in a period of time
- Allow some sites only in a certain amount of time per hour

And it has many options

Comment: But it can't be remote controlled